# How to Decide when to Implement a DLL?

Tags: dll, class-library, code-duplication

At which point do you decide that some of your subroutines and common code should be placed in a class library or DLL? In one of my applications, I would like to share some of my common code between different projects (as we all know, it's a [programming sin to duplicate code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/curlys-law-do-one-thing.html)).

The vast majority of my code is all within a single project. I also have one small utility that's partitioned from the main executable that runs with elevated permissions for a sole purpose. The two items have, at most, three subroutines in common. Should these common subroutines be placed and called from a class library? How do you decide when to do this? When you have at least one shared subroutine? Twenty-plus lines of code?

I don't believe that this should be language specific or framework dependent, but if so, I'm using the .NET framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more ways to share code between applications than with a DLL.  From what it sounds like, you're not talking about a lot of code, so it sounds like you don't need to worry about it too much.

In general, I use the following rule of thumb:

- For trivial code duplication (a couple simple 1-2 line functions, that are easy to understand and debug) I'll just copy and paste the code.
- For more complicated functions (a small library of stand-alone helper functions, contained in a file or two, which require a modest level of maintenance and debugging) I'll simply include the file in both projects (either by linking, or defining a subrepository, or something like that).
- For more extensive code sharing (a group of interrelated classes, or a database communication layer, which is useful for multiple projects) I'll refactor them out into a standalone library, and package and distribute them using whatever's appropriate for whatever I'm programming in.

Because the complexity of managing your code increases by an order of magnitude for each step (when you're packaging DLLs for multiple projects you now need to think about versioning issues) you only want to move to the next level when you need to.  It doesn't sound like you're feeling the pain of handling your common code yet, and if that's the case there's no real need.

Answer (score 0):

If code is shared between multiple applications, then it has to reside in a DLL or class library.

For a larger application you might also want to break different subsystems of the application into separate libraries. That way each project can focus on one particular task. This simplifies the structure of your application and makes it easier to find any one piece of code. For example, you might have a GUI application with different DLL's  (.NET projects) for:

- Working with a specific Network protocol
- Accessing common code, for example utility classes
- Access to legacy code (via PInvoke)
- etc...